# Access IndexDB when Promise gets query error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexeddb

I am doing a Progressive Web App and I want to access the data I have stored on IndexedDB when the ajax reponse fails. The data gets filled when the query is successful. Below is one of the attempts. In comments is the original format before I inserted the offline part (I already had base code).

```
getAudits: (startOfMonth, endOfMonth) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request
    .get(url + "api/?method=Audit.data")
    .query({
      pageLength: "all",
      format: "json",
      where: startOfMonth
        ? Utils.hashQuery(
            "a.date",
            "between",
            [startOfMonth, endOfMonth].toString()
          )
        : "",
      ts: new Date().getTime()
    })
    .end((error, response) => {
        var res;
      if (error) {
          res = getCacheAudits(startOfMonth, endOfMonth);
        //reject(error);
      } else {
        let _audits = [];
        const audits = Utils.toArray(JSON.parse(response.text).rows);
        audits.forEach(audit => {
          _audits.push(audit);
          //console.log(audit);

        });
        res = _audits;
        getServerAudits(_audits);
        //resolve(res);
      }
      resolve(res);
    });
});
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to handle this correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to insert the data coming from ajax results into indexeddb right ?

Comment: No, that I have sorted out. I want to get the indexedDB when the ajax result fails, like due to being offline and such.

Comment: So you want the same query to use which you have used for ajax for getting data from indexeddb right? Want to use where option right ?

Comment: I guess so. And also, can I do that inside the if(error) part? I was trying there, but it wasn't working. It could be due to not being using the where option, but rather iterating it and returning the data I needed and putting it in a array. This is my first time doing this sort of stuff so I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you copy `Utils.toArray(JSON.parse(response.text).rows` to audits, _audits and res, they are all the same.

Also not sure what `getServerAudits` is supposed to do because it doesn't return anything and you're not doing anything with it's return value (usually a bad design sign to call functions and ignore their return)

You could probably do something like this:

```
getAudits: (startOfMonth, endOfMonth) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request
      .get(url + "api/?method=Audit.data")
      .query({
        pageLength: "all",
        format: "json",
        where: startOfMonth
          ? Utils.hashQuery(
              "a.date",
              "between",
              [startOfMonth, endOfMonth].toString()
            )
          : "",
        ts: new Date().getTime()
      })
      .end((error, response) =>
          (error)
            ? reject([error,startOfMonth, endOfMonth])
            : resolve(Utils.toArray(JSON.parse(response.text).rows))
      )
    })
    .catch(
      ([err,startOfMonth, endOfMonth]) =>
        getCacheAudits(startOfMonth, endOfMonth)
    )
    .then(
      audits => {
        //not sure what this does, you don't seem to care about it's
        //  result because your code doesn't do anything with it
        getServerAudits(audits);
        //probably want to save audits to local storage here
        return Promise.all([
          audits,
          saveCacheAudits(startOfMonth,endOfMonth,audits)
        ]);
      }
    )
    .then(
      //resolve audits
      ([audits])=>audits
    )
}
```

Comment: The audits and _audits was already created when I got  the base code.

getServerAudits(audits just creates a audits database that will be stored with id as key) and in case it's already created it just pushes the information as it normally would.

Comment: @RúbenSantos I changed the code since reading and writing to indexeddb probably returns a promise. You don't care for the results of `getServerAudits` nor care to know if it fails I assume.

Comment: Correct. What's needed from getServer is the AuditsDB that's defined as global. And I'm assuming it doesn't fail as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make this easy with indexedb library jsstore -

```
var con= new JsStore.Instance(<db_name>);

getCacheAudits: (startOfMonth, endOfMonth)=>{
    return con.select({
    From: "Table_Name",
    Where:
        {
            startOfMonth:startOfMonth,
            endOfMonth: endOfMonth
        }
    })
}

getAudits: (startOfMonth, endOfMonth) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request
        .get(url + "api/?method=Audit.data")
        .query({
        pageLength: "all",
        format: "json",
        where: startOfMonth
            ? Utils.hashQuery(
                "a.date",
                "between",
                [startOfMonth, endOfMonth].toString()
            )
            : "",
        ts: new Date().getTime()
        })
        .end((error, response) => {
            var res;
            if (error) {
                //get the data from indexeddb
                getCacheAudits.
                then(function (results){
                    resolve(results);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    reject(error._message);
                }); 
            } else {
                let _audits = [];
                const audits = Utils.toArray(JSON.parse(response.text).rows);
                audits.forEach(audit => {
                _audits.push(audit);
                //console.log(audit);

                });
                res = _audits;
                getServerAudits(_audits);
                resolve(res);
            }
        //resolve(res);
        });
    });
}
```

You can also use where (http://jsstore.net/tutorial/where) and all others options to query the data.

If you are using angular to create the app, check out this article - http://ujjwalguptaofficial.blogspot.in/2017/10/angular4-crud-operation-in-indexeddb.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Supposedly (it could have an error) getCache already returns an array with audits stored in cache. I have it iterating the AuditsDB and inserting each audit on the array. Most certainly not the quickest way to do so.

Comment: Updated the answer, please see. I have created the function getCacheAudit and i am returning a promise from there and caching it inside the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem. It wasn't actually just in this part, but in the getCacheAudits function too.

The getCacheAudits call became:

```
getCacheAudits(startOfMonth, endOfMonth, function (res) {
                        resolve(res);
                    })
```

And in the getCacheAudits function was added a callback

```
function getCacheAudits(startOfMonth, endOfMonth, callback){
let initOpenReq = indexedDB.open("AuditsDB");
let agregate = [];
initOpenReq.onsuccess = function() {
    var db = initOpenReq.result;
    var transaction = db.transaction("audits","readonly");
    var obj_store   = transaction.objectStore("audits");

    obj_store.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event){
        let cursor = event.target.result;
        if(cursor){
            agregate.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        }else{
            callback(agregate);
        }
    };
}
```

There are a few more bells a whistles in the function, but this made it work properly.

Sorry for not including the function right from the beginning.